# How to you remove a Sharepoint Tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, tenant

How do you remove a tenant from SharePoint?

I've read you can't CHANGE a SharePoint Tenant but can you delete one and install a new one?

Ultimately I want to remove Company123.sharepoint.com and setup Company.sharepoint.com

1. How to remove a tenant?
2. Do I have to remove the tenant from ALL Microsoft 365 services?

Answer (score 0):

To delete a Microsoft 365 tenant, you need to cancel all the subscriptions from the Microsoft 365 admin center.

You can find more information at: [Cancel your subscription](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/subscriptions/cancel-your-subscription)

Also check:

1. [What happens when you cancel a subscription](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/subscriptions/cancel-your-subscription#what-happens-when-you-cancel-a-subscription)
2. [Delete abandoned Office 365 Tenant](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_account-mso_other-mso_o365b/delete-abandoned-office-365-tenant/3df21f18-6120-4e3c-a962-1bd1ab0a4feb)

Comment: glad it helped you @Mark. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.